# Want to get Text from UIWebView with any method

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, epub

I am loading XHTML file content in **UIWebView** which is in ePub.

Now i **need to get** the Whatever **Tex is present on screen**.

and the Files are coming dynamically so Text are also coming dynamically.

I am loading whole XHTML content in UIWebView and with **pageScroll** in Java Script i am scrolling the page in UIWebView.

but i am getting all the content of UIWebView but need only that content that are **presently visible on screen**.

Is any one know this ?

I asked the similar question but no one answered it...

[Get tag's and values from Jscript where pageScroll happen in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480212/get-tags-and-values-from-jscript-where-pagescroll-happen-in-uiwebview)

[How to Get HTML tag which seen in UIWebView Screen out of all HTML tag loaded in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445210/how-to-get-html-tag-which-seen-in-uiwebview-screen-out-of-all-html-tag-loaded-in)

Any kind of direction is appreciated...

Comment: that question is asked by me and there isn't any answer...

Comment: It is frowned upon to ask the same question again here. There's a [few documented steps](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) to increase visibility on your question. Reasking it is not one of those.

Comment: Try to get your whole XHTML structure By NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]; then parse your desire data from HTML

Comment: @AJPatel i got whole HTML by that but html contents are so big so i am loading all the content in UIWebView and then scrolling it. because it contains some images too. so i need to get the content that are visible on the iPhone's screen.